# Stopping or Pausing MediaPlayer on click using single media player

Tags: android, media-player

How can I stop or pause MediaPlayer using only 1 media player?
For example I have Grid View. What I want when I click on button it's playing sound.
But here is tricky part. When I click again on button, its not stopping it but instead it's resting sound and playing it from start.
I tried to add

```
else{
mp.pause
mp.seekTo(0);
}
```

But it didn't work. It gave me errors
Here is my Code:

```
case 24:
                    if(mp!=null)
                    {
                        mp.release();
                        mp=null;
                    }

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Glavni.this, R.raw.s25snd);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
```

Comment: What were the errors you got? It's not very clear what you're asking..

Comment: I am asking how can I when I click again on same button pause or stop Media player instead of playing it again from start.
and error was `Syntax error on token "else", delete this token`

Comment: mp.pause() and mp.start() should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pause the track

```
Mediaplayer.pause();
length=Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

save length and than resume it with that length

```
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
if (mp == null) {
    initMediaPlayer();
}
...
if (mPrepared && mHasStarted && mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.pause();
} else if (mPrepared) {
    mHasStarted = true;
    mp.start();
}
```

Where mPrepared is true once the media player has been prepared.  If you look really closely at the state diagram and table, you'll notice it's an error to call pause() before the playback has been started.  If this is indeed intentional, then you need the mHasStarted flag as well.